# differences between writing scripts to mysql and hadoop

Tags: mysql, sql, hadoop

recently I got a question on a recruitment interview about what are the differences in script writing for mysql and hadoop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is complicated to talk about differences because they have nothing to do with it. `Mysql` is a relational database management system and yet `Hadoop` is a collection of utilities to perform distributed work in clusters, where the core of the system is the HDFS or hadoop distributed file system.

So when you write a script for Mysql, you do it in SQL and you do it for Data Manipulation or for Data Definition of relational tables

When you write a script for Hadoop, you can use shell scripting or other programming language, and you can do it to manipulate files or to distribute work in your system (with MapReduce).

Maybe the person who asked you the question did not know the differences or wanted you to show them.

Comment: You could still write **HiveQL**, though

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, but that´s a Hive script, not a Hadoop Script. That shows that the questionn is not well done, so the person who asked didn´t know the difference

Comment: If I were asked the same question in an interview, I would have immeadiately assumed they referred to Hive scripts